# What's the difference between Mediators, Co-Variates, Moderators and Confounders terms?

Tags: terminology, predictor

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on the difference between the above-mentioned terms since I see them used frequently in many research publications I've read.

If I have an outcome variable A and predictor variable C, with B being a '3rd party' variable that affects the outcome, what makes variable B:

A Mediator, or
A Co-Variate, or
A Moderator, or
A Confounder?

I believe the relationships between A and B and A and C have to be statistically significant. Same with A, B (as dual predictors) with C.

When is it appropriate to use either of the above four variables to determine its effect on the outcome? They all seem very similar to me, as all affect outcome C through variable B. Literature search has confused me even more, unfortunately.

I'm looking for a simple, hopefully easy-to-explain reason why I would use one of the four over the other. Thanks!

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example you assume that `A` "listens" to `C`, or in other words `C` predicts `A`:

`C -> A`

#### Confounder

In this setting, when you talk about a confounder `B` means that `B` influences both `C` and `A`. For example, you want to predict the effect of education on salary. In this case, your `B` could be things like socioeconomic status or other demographic factors (gender, age, etc.). Having rich and influential parents may make it easier for you to get access to top universities, which may get you access to higher paying jobs; but having influential parents may also give you access to higher paying jobs regardless of your education:

`C <- B -> A`

In statistical models, you can control for confounders by adding them to your model, in which case those predictor variables are also often called  **covariates**. I have seen these terms used interchangeably.

#### Mediator

On the other hand, a mediator is the mechanism that explains the relationship of a predictor variable on the outcome. For example, you are applying treatment (`C`) to a plant seedling which increases its growth (`A`), however, in reality, `C` positively influences the soil microbial community (`B`), which directly affects the plants' ability to take up nutrients faster:

`C -> B -> A`

For mediation analysis see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)

###### Edit to address Graham's comment below

Be aware that when you think that a variable acts as a mediator you likley don't want to include it into your model together with your predictor variable as it might cause unstable estimates and incorrect standard errors due to collinearity with the predictor.

In Pearl's "The Book of Why" he even goes to say that:

> ... mistaking a mediator for a confounder is one of the deadliest sins in causal inference and may lead to the most outragous errors. The latter invites adjustment; the former forbids it.

#### Moderator

In the hypothetical example above, a moderator could be soil water status. Depending on soil moisture (`M`), the relationship of treatment `C` on growth `A` depends, or is moderated by soil water content. The moderator in this sense, represents an **interaction effect**. This could look something like this (probably not formally correct):

`C -> B*M -> A`

You could test whether or not a variable acts as a moderator by including it as an interaction term in your statistical model.

Note: What I presented above, are overly simplified examples and if you are really interested in a clear *treatment* (pun-intended) of this topic, you should look into Judea Pearl's work (http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/jp_home.html).

> I'm looking for a simple, hopefully easy-to-explain reason why I would use one of the four over the other.

I hope given those examples, it is clear that you cannot really "use" any of those in your analysis. You can identify them in your scientific model and then account for them in your statistical models.

Comment: Great answer! Just an additional comment, that if you think that a variable might be a mediator, you probably DON'T want to control for it in a model, and if you think a variable might be a moderator, then you might want to include an interaction term to test if that is true or not.

Comment: @GrahamWright good point! I was contemplating including it yesterday but wasn't sure if I should. Now given your comment I agree that I should have mentioned it (which I did now).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and well-explained answer, @Stefan!

Comment: @DavidMusoke I'm glad you found it useful. In this case you could also consider acceping the answer (clicking the checkmark symbol next to it). Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thank you once again@Stefan. This needs to be a pinned response, imho.